# Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a usercontrol with a gridview on it that has one column.
This column is a boundfield column and in the code-behind bound to a datatable.

In the page-init sub:

```
 myResult = sd.getUsers(dt, err)
If myResult = True Then

  Me.dgUsers.DataSource = dt
  Me.dgUsers.DataBind()
Else
  pnUsersMain.Controls.Clear()
  Dim lit As New Literal
  lit.Text = err
  pnUsersMain.Controls.Add(lit)
End If
```

During the binding I add on "OnClick" event to each row:

```
 Private Sub dgUsers_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles dgUsers.RowDataBound
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(dgUsers, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex.ToString))
```

End Sub

Now when I click on a row in the gridview, this error appears:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I have tried:

- placing the gridview on an update panel.

While on the update panel, if I put a postbacktrigger to this gridview, I get the above error. If I remove the postbacktrigger, nothing happens at all.

- placing the databinding code in the Render sub.

It did not change anything.

- update panel updates at different places in the code-behind, same error result.
- replacing the boundfield column with a (link) buttonfield column did as expected, but then I will have to instruct the user to click on the text and not an empty part of the column. So that is not what I want. I need the whole gridview cell to be clickable.

What else can I do to get rid of this annoying error?

Comment: This error occurs when you add dynamic controls to the page without a "normal" process. Since the objects are not properly registered ASP.net triggers this error or possible code injection. Make sure all your controls on the page has a UniqueID

Comment: All my controls on the page have an unique ID.